# Why is the 'this' keyword needed in objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

From sololearn

```
function mathCalc (height, weight) {
  this.height = height;
  this.weight = weight;
  // this.sampleCalc = ; (taken out)
}
```

Why do I need to do:

```
this.height = height;

this.weight = weight;
```

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: What alternative would you propose?

Comment: I'm believe that the `this` keyword sets it as a property of the object,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a keyword for the **function's caller** for function expressions and function declarations. For constructor functions (which I will demonstrate below) and object methods, `this` refers to the object itself. Here are examples of the types mentioned:

```
function myFunc() { return this; } //function declaration
const myVar = function() { return this; } //function expression
const obj = {a: 1, whatIsA: function() { return this.a } } //whatIsA is an object method
```

If you call either of the above functions from the global context (not inside another function), `this` is the Window object. The browser defaults `this` to the Window (which when you think about it, is the caller of the function since your browser ran the file).

```
myFunc(); //outputs "Window" obj
myVar(); //also outputs "Window" obj
```

For constructor functions instantiated with `new`, `this` is bound to the newly created object.

I think the best way to show why `this` is so useful is to give an example. Examine the following code:

```
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bones = 0;
    this.addBone = function(numOfBones) {
        this.bones += numOfBones;
        return this;
    }
}

const clifford = new Dog('Clifford');
```

We have a constructor function (meaning we're going to be creating **new objects** from this function) called Dog.

Consider what happens when we create a `new Dog` named "Clifford". The `new` keyword creates a brand new object in memory for Clifford, which is an instance of the Dog constructor function. So since we created something that didn't exist before, `this` refers to the object itself. If we replaced `this.name = name` with `let myName = name` what would happen? We wouldn't be able to access myName because myName isn't part of our brand `new` instance of the Dog object.

Let's give Clifford a few bones.

```
clifford.addBone(1).addBone(2).addBone(3);
console.log(clifford.bones); //outputs 6
```

How is it possible we can chain methods as we did above? Because the method returns `this`!

> [When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Examples)

So we're returning the object after adding a bone to Clifford's bones. This gives us back the object itself again.

Arrow functions behave slightly differently. `this` [is inherited from the current lexical scope and not the caller.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Very good explanation! It helped a lot! To clarify, "this" refers to the owner or the caller and I can use it to communicate with other objects, and use it for objects.

Comment: Yeah “communicate with other objects” meaning communicate with the owner/caller as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short `this` is the owner object of the function. If you had two objects or elements that called upon a function - how would you place the appropriate value in the appropriate element that called it? Using `this` can eliminate the need for duplicate code etc.

Technically you don't *HAVE* to use it; but it has its uses.

You can [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp).

Here's a little click test snippet, where I can have one function for alerting `this` clicked div id rather than having to write one for each div;

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < div.length; ++i) {
  div[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">Click Test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Click Test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Click Test 3</div>
```

Mind you, this is easier in jQuery - but I didn't feel the need to include the CDN for this example. However, it would look something like this;

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
  alert(this.id);
})
```

Comment: "this" isn't the owner, it's the caller

Comment: I understand your point completely. I think it depends where you read about ``this`` - for example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp - refers to it as the owner object or global object depending how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

`height` and `weight` are only parameters for the arguments passed into the function.  If you're learning, it might help to use different names.

`this` refers to the function itself.  When treated as an object/class, it will retain the values.  Notice in the object output below that `h` and `w` are not retained, `height` and `weight` are.  Also notice that `one` and `two` have different values, the same value that was passed into the function when they were initialized.

```js
function mathCalc (h, w) {
  this.height = h
  this.weight = w
}

let one = new mathCalc(1,3)
let two = new mathCalc(2,4)

console.log('one:',one)
console.log('two:',two)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a function that only gets called once, it makes complete sense to avoid `this`. However, for persistent state, `this` can be useful. Note that `this` only gets rebound when the `new` keyword is used.

```
function Worm() {
  this.size = 1;
  this.grow = function() {
    ++this.size;
  }
}
const wormy = new Worm();
console.log(wormy.size);
wormy.grow();
console.log(wormy.size);
```

With ES6 Javascript, there is a much cleaner way to take advantage of this.

```
class Worm {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 1;
  }
  grow() {
    ++this.size
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

it's an easier way to write the name of an object, useful for larger programs that have many objects.